# Bulk duplicate files in different directories

Tags: cmd, duplicates, metadata

Sorry I am not sure if I ask in the right place. I have a problem on metadata.

```
Folder0 
　├ Folder1
　│　　├ Folder1.png
　│　　└ Other files
　├ Folder2
　│　　├ Folder2.png
　│　　└ Other files
　└ Folder3
　 　　├ Folder3.png
　 　　└ Other files
```

To

```
Folder0 
　├ Folder1
　│　　├ Folder1.png
　│　　├ Cover.png
　│　　└ Other files
　├ Folder2
　│　　├ Folder2.png
　│　　├ Cover.png
　│　　└ Other files
　└ Folder3
　 　　├ Folder3.png
　 　　├ Cover.png
　 　　└ Other files
```

Is it possible to run a command line or if any software can help me duplicates the *.png in different subfolders to another png and rename it to Cover.png? Will be the best to ignore if Cover.png exists.
That will save me a lot of time since I have over 2000 folders like this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: for help with your code, show your code and explain how it doesn't do what you want. If you don't have any code yet, visit [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt) and take a look at the `copy`, `xcopy` and `move` commands. Also `for` may be useful (depends on what exactly you want to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org) using this command

`exiftool -r -ext png -o . -Filename=%d/cover.png /path/to/directories/`

Exiftool will recursively read all the directories looking for PNG files.  When it encounters one, it will create a copy named cover.png.  If the cover.png already exists,  exiftool will display `1 files weren't updated due to errors` but will continue.  If there are multiple PNG files, only the first one it reads will be copied and the others will return the above error.

Breakdown:
[`-r` (recurse) option](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) - Recurse through subdirectories
[`-ext png`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) - Process only PNG files
[`-o`.](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#o-OUTFILE-or-FMT--out) - Set the output file or directory name.  When using the `Filename` tag (next option in the command), this causes the file to be copied instead of recreated in the output directory.  The dot is used as a dummy argument in this cases because the use of the `Filename` tag overrides the output directory used here
`-Filename=%d/cover.png` - This will be the name used by the previous `-o` option.  The `%d` is the directory of the file that is being processed (copied), which completes the target path to the new `cover.png` file.
`/path/to/directories/` - replace this with the path to the top level of the directory tree you want to process.  If you have CDed into the top directory, use a dot `.` to represent the current directory.

Comment: I gotta thank you once again, this really saved me a lot of time lol

Comment: For the episodes, is it possible to duplicate a jpg or txt for 30 times and rename it by fix string + incremental of 1? Or at the very least, duplicated the file for 30 times in the same folder. I can use bulkrenamer to fix the name after.

Comment: Unfortunately, exiftool can only make one copy at a time.

Comment: Is there any other software similar to exiftool which can chop the image to half in bulk? The backdrop supports limit area of an image. It seems exiftool doesnt support this function. It may take me a while to chop them all by manual -_-

Comment: Do you mean resize them?  If you're on Windows, you can do this with [Irfanview](https://irfanview-forum.de/).